# Why does my SQL query keep throwing an error when I am using the right column name and the correct statement?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am trying to create a book Database system using MySQL Python and Flask. My 3 columns in my Books table are title, author, and publish_year.

I have a SQL Command that says

```
"SELECT * FROM Books WHERE title=" + str(title)"
```

And whenever I try to call my endpoint with

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/getbookfromtitle/Twilight
```

I get the error

```
 Unknown column 'Twilight' in 'where clause'
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?
My full Flask function is

```
@app.route("/getbookfromtitle/<title>", methods=["GET"])
def getBookFromTitle(title):
    if request.method == "GET":
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE title=" + str(title)
        mycursor.execute(sql)
        result = mycursor.fetchall()

        for x in result:
            print(x)
        return str(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I think I figured it out.

I have to do

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE title=%s", (title,))
```

After I did this, it worked for some reason.